# Lowest and Highest detected EM radiation

Tags: electromagnetism

What is the highest and lowest frequency EM wave detected? In theory, the maximum possible EM radiation must have a wavelength greater than Planck length. However, is there any maximum possible wavelength? Also, how charged particles block the very low-frequency radio waves from entering Earth?

Comment: *In theory, the maximum possible EM radiation must have a wavelength greater than Planck length.* There is no widely-accepted theory in which the Planck length is the shortest possible length. This is speculative.